# MongoJS, Node, MongoLab - How to get the database online

Tags: mongodb, ionic-framework, mlab, mongojs

I have created an hybrid application with Ionic, MongoJS, Angular JS (Mean Stack).
My application worked fine, locally. This means my mongod (Mongo Service) and my mongo ran locally on my pc. I also have a server.js (node) which is located locally.

Now I would like to use MongoLab (MongoDB as a Service) to change the location of my database from local to online.

I intented to change just the connection path, but for some reason I receive an undefined through my http get request.

My code:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

//var db = mongojs('nzbaienfurtdb', ['nzbaienfurtdb']); // This is my old mongojs which ran locally and worked fine.
var databaseUrl = 'mongodb://dbuser:password@ds045604.mongolab.com:45604/nzbaienfurtdb';
var db = mongojs(databaseUrl, ['nzbaienfurtdb']); // database online with MongoLab
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/www"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/nzbaienfurtdb', function (req, res) {
console.log("I received a GET request")

db.nzbaienfurtdb.find(function (err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
   });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("server running on 3000");
```

This is a part of my get request out of a service:

service.js

```
return {

getUsers: function(){""
$http.get("/nzbaienfurtdb")

.success(function(data, status, headers, config){

            headers("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            headers("Pragma", "no-cache");
            headers("Expires", 0);
            users = angular.fromJson(data);

           })

.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log('Data could not be loaded, try again later');

         })
     return users;

    }
```

MongoLab has been setup already.

My questions:

Why do I get an undefined for my http GET Request?
What happens with my server.js file when I want to deploy the Ionic App on for example an Android Phone? Is the server running on the device?

Since I have changed the var db variable i get also the following error message in my chrome console:

--------- ERROR CODE:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.fromJson    (http://localhost:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8764:14)
at http://localhost:3000/js/userServices.js:23:27
at http://localhost:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15737:11
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19197:81)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19197:81)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19283:26
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20326:28)
at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20138:31)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20430:24)
```

I hope somebody can help me out, I am fighting now for ages!

Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: add one braces at last of return users;

Comment: I tested this code on my  local machine and it's working. I got this message when i hit the same url as you defined obove , Msg: "I received a GET request".

Comment: Hello, yes i get the message but the request is undefined, for some reason... ,braces already added just not copied into this post, i am sorry... any other comments?

Comment: You mean to say that this line(console.log(docs)) is showing undefined right ?

Comment: yep, exactly. I dont know why, before I changed the var db to online it worked fine, now when I try to get it from the MongoLab it gives me a undefined.

Comment: What is your collection name on which you want to fire the query ?

Comment: From the docs for mongojs: Attention MongoDB 3 users: In MongoDB 3 the default auth mechanism is ScramSHA1 not MongoCR (the default auth mechanism in mongojs). When connecting to an auth enabled MongoDB 3 instance providing the authMechanism option value 'ScramSHA1' is mandatory!

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved after ages!

I had to enable the API on the website of mongolab in my configuration.